# Merge multiple XML files into one CSV file (C++ or Python, Scikit-Learn)

Tags: python, xml, csv, opencv, scikit-learn

I have a folder with a lot of XML files, each of them containing a histogram of a different image (done with OpenCV on Visual Studio). They share the same structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<my_histogram type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>256</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <data>
    1685. 641. 7. 7. 4. 0. 3. 2. 1. 4. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
    0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 5. 0. 0. 3. 1. 0. 0. 323. 590.
    1. 5. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.
    3. 0. 0. 616. 264. 1. 4. 1. 0. 0. 0. 2. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
    0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 3. 2. 0. 0. 2. 5. 0. 2.
    565. 2228. 5. 10. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3.
    2. 316. 642. 1. 0. 4. 4. 2. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
    0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 3. 228.
    1136. 0. 1. 1. 7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
    1. 2. 6. 2. 0. 628. 2129. 1. 1. 2. 1. 4. 4. 3. 11. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
    0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 1. 11. 1. 0. 2. 7.
    2. 13. 1358. 3860. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.</data></my_histogram>
</opencv_storage>
```

Inexperienced here, what I would like to do, is to take all these XML files (all these histograms) and merge them into one CSV file, that I want to use on Python (with Scikit-Learn). What is a good way to do that? I've found some XML to CSV converters and all that, none of them did what I wanted and most posts are about XML to Excel. Is there a specific way to do this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Actually no. I'm still trying a way to figure it out. I've thought of re-exporting all histograms, or loading them in Python and then create the CSV file from there.

Comment: Use `cv2.FileStorage` to read all histograms from xml file to Mat then use the following to save csv. Unfortunately, `cv2.FileStorage` does not support csv. http://answers.opencv.org/question/73223/cant-create-csv-file/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will look into it and let you know how it goes. Much appreciated.

Comment: Done. All of them are now in once CSV file. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.